# Why deployment getting failed on Render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, render

I am trying to deploy chat app on Render but it's getting failed, I don't understand why,
I tried almost 12-13 times, I've changed localhost to Render url in frontend and socket but still it's not getting deployed.

Can someone help to fix, it's getting frustrated, here is the github link:
https://github.com/sanadqazi/mern--realtime-chat-app

```
==> Build successful 
==> Deploying...
==> Using Node version 20.11.1 (default)
==> Docs on specifying a Node version: https://render.com/docs/node-version
==> Running 'node run start'
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
  throw err;
  ^
Error: Cannot find module '/opt/render/project/src/run'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1144:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:985:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:135:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:28:49 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
Node.js v20.11.1
```

Root folder - Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "chat-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "server": "nodemon backend/server.js",
    "start": "node backend/server.js",
    "build": "npm install && npm install --prefix frontend && npm run build --prefix frontend"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Sanad Qazi",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "mongoose": "^8.2.0",
    "socket.io": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^3.1.0"
  }
}
```

Backend/server.js:

```
import path from "path";
import express from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import cookieParser from "cookie-parser";

import authRoutes from "./routes/auth.routes.js";
import messageRoutes from "./routes/message.routes.js";
import userRoutes from "./routes/user.routes.js";

import connectToMongoDB from "./db/connectToMongoDB.js";
import { app, server } from "./socket/socket.js";

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const __dirname = path.resolve();

dotenv.config();

app.use(express.json()); // to parse the incoming requests with JSON payloads (from req.body)
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use("/api/auth", authRoutes);
app.use("/api/messages", messageRoutes);
app.use("/api/users", userRoutes);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/frontend/dist")));

app.get("*", (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "frontend", "dist", "index.html"));
});

server.listen(PORT, () => {
    connectToMongoDB();
    console.log(`Server Running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Frontend/package.json:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "chat-app": "file:..",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-hot-toast": "^2.4.1",
    "react-icons": "^5.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.22.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.7.4",
    "zustand": "^4.5.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.56",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.19",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.2.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.17",
    "daisyui": "^4.7.2",
    "eslint": "^8.56.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.33.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.5",
    "postcss": "^8.4.35",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.1",
    "vite": "^5.1.4"
  }
}
```

Comment: `node run` is not a command. You might be looking for  `npm run start` ?